# Tengo un error al momento de actualizar la tabla egresos y la tabla detalle_egresos

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Este es el código del método update en EgresoController:

```
public function update(Request $request)
  {
    if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();

      $id = $request->id;

      $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Guayaquil');

      $egreso = Egreso::findOrFail($id); //busco el registro del egreso
      $egreso->idusuario = \Auth::user()->id;
      $egreso->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
      $egreso->tipo_comprobante = $request->tipo_comprobante;
      $egreso->serie_comprobante = $request->serie_comprobante;
      $egreso->num_comprobante = $request->num_comprobante;
      $egreso->fecha_hora = $mytime->toDateString();
      $egreso->descuento = $request->descuento;
      $egreso->iva = $request->iva;
      $egreso->total = $request->total;
      $egreso->estado = 'Registrado';
      $egreso->save();

      $detalles = $request->data; //Array de los detalles

      foreach ($detalles as $ep => $det)
      {
        $detalle = DetalleEgreso::where('detalle_egresos.idegreso', '=', $id)->get();
        $detalle->idegreso = $id;
        $detalle->iditem = $det['iditem'];
        $detalle->cantidad = $det['cantidad'];
        $detalle->descuento = $det['descuento'];
        $detalle->precio = $det['precio'];
        $detalle->save();
      }

      DB::commit();
    }catch(Exception $e) {
      DB::rollBack();
    }
  }
```

Al momento de hacer la petición ajax con axios, me devuelve un error con el código 500. El cliente está hecho con Vue. EL hecho es que trato de actualizar un registro pero tengo ese incoveniente el cual no he podido resolver

Comment: Puedes debuggear usando este codigo ```return response()->json(['data' => 'tu variable o dato aquí'])``` y hacer con ```console.log()``` en tu petición de ajax, para de esta manera encontrar en que punto de tu código se esta cayendo.

Comment: Error 500 es una respuesta http. Mira el trazo de la excepción para identificar cual es el error. Puedes encontrarlo en `storage/logs/laravel.log `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en como estás actualizando los detalles.

```
$detalle = DetalleEgreso::where('detalle_egresos.idegreso', '=', $id)->get();
```

El método `get()` devuelve una [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#collections) con todos los resultados, no devulve un único resultado. Con lo cual, `$detalle` no es un objeto al que le podes asignas las propiedades `idingreso`, `iditem`, etc.

---

Si `DetalleEgreso` tiene que devolver un solo resultado, reemplaza `get()` por [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

```
$detalle = DetalleEgreso::where('detalle_egresos.idegreso', '=', $id)->first();
```

---

Pero si puede devolver varios resultados, vas a tener que recorrerlos a todos:

```
foreach ($detalles as $ep => $det) {
    $detalles = DetalleEgreso::where('detalle_egresos.idegreso', '=', $id)->get();

    foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
        $detalle->idegreso = $id;
        $detalle->iditem = $det['iditem'];
        $detalle->cantidad = $det['cantidad'];
        $detalle->descuento = $det['descuento'];
        $detalle->precio = $det['precio'];
        $detalle->save();
    }
}
```